# what is device verity state

Tags: android, android-source, bootloader

`device verity state is: ENABLED`

I got above line in boot log. May I know, what it will do exactly?
I have read in android source link, but did not understand.

Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android can use `dm-verity` to protect non-data partitions against manipulation ([link](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity), [link](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/DMVerity)).

The goal is to prevent an attacker (with physical access to the device) from inserting malicious code, e.g. into low-level Android services stored on the `/system` or `/recovery` partition.

For partitions marked with the `verity` flag in the `fstab`, at build-time the dm-verity hash tree of the partition is computed. The hash tree is signed with an RSA key and appended as meta-data to the partition. The public part of the RSA key is added to the `boot` partition.

At boot-time, the kernel verifies the integrity of the signed hash tree in the partition meta-data using the RSA public key stored in the `boot` partition. Then it can compute the hash tree of the partition and compare it to the hash tree from the meta-data. If there is a mismatch, the kernel refuses to boot.

Therefore, if an attacker manipulates the partition, the hash tree computed at boot-time will not match the hash tree from the partition meta-data. If the attacker also manipulates the hash tree from the partition meta-data, the signature validation with the RSA public key will fail.

Of course you then need an additional mechanism to ensure the integrity of the `boot` partition. This can be done with Secure-Boot-like mechanisms where the `boot` partition is again signed with another (RSA) key and the public part of that key is embedded at a lower level (vendor-specific). Such a chaining of verification mechanisms is referred to as a chain of trust. Ideally, you would want a chain of trust to extend down to the hardware level, with some vendor key being burned into the chip.